# Matrix multiplication while subsetting elements from matrices and storing in a new matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matmul

I am attempting a `numpy.matmul` call using as variables

- Matrix `A` of dimensions `(p, t, q)`
- Matrix `B` of dimensions `(r, t)`.
- A `categories` vector of shape `r` and `p` categories, used to take slices of `B` and define the index of `A` do use.

The multiplications are done iteratively using the indices of each category. For each category `p_i`, I extract from A a submatrix (`t, q`). Then, I multiply those with a subset of B (`x, t`), where `x` is a mask defined by `r == p_i`. Finally, the matrix multiplication of `(x, t)` and `(t, q)` produces the output `(x, q)` which is stored at `S[x]`.

I have noted that I cannot figure out a non-iterative version of this algorithm. The first snippet describes an iterative solution. The second one is an attempt at what I would wish to get, where everything is calculated as a single-step and would be presumably faster. However, it is incorrect because matrix A has three dimensions instead of two. Maybe there is no way to do this in NumPy with a single call, and in general, looking for advice/ideas to try out.

Thanks!

```py
import numpy as np
p, q, r, t = 2, 9, 512, 4
# data initialization (random)
np.random.seed(500)
S = np.random.rand(r, q)
A = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(p, t, q))
B = np.random.rand(r, t)
categories = np.random.randint(0, p, r)

print('iterative') # iterative
for i in range(p):
    # print(i)
    a = A[i, :, :]
    mask = categories == i
    b = B[mask]
    print(b.shape, a.shape, S[mask].shape,
          np.matmul(b, a).shape)
    S[mask] = np.matmul(b, a)

print(S.shape)
```

a simple way to write it down

```py
S = np.random.rand(r, q)
print(A[:p,:,:].shape)
result = np.matmul(B, A[:p,:,:])

# iterative assignment
i = 0
S[categories == i] = result[i, categories == i, :]
i = 1
S[categories == i] = result[i, categories == i, :]
```

The next snippet will produce an error during the multiplication step.

```py
# attempt to multiply once, indexing all categories only once (not possible)
np.random.seed(500)
S = np.random.rand(r, q)
# attempt to use the categories vector
a = A[categories, :, :]
b = B[categories]
# due to the shapes of the arrays, this multiplication is not possible
print('\nsingle step (error due to shapes of the matrix a')
print(b.shape, a.shape, S[categories].shape)
S[categories] = np.matmul(b, a)
print(scores.shape)
```

```bash
iterative
(250, 4) (4, 9) (250, 9) (250, 9)
(262, 4) (4, 9) (262, 9) (262, 9)
(512, 9)


single step (error due to shapes of the 2nd matrix a).
(512, 4) (512, 4, 9) (512, 9)
```

Comment: what is the final output you are looking for? `np.sum(np.matmul(b, a)))`? lets say you did this without any explicit iteration, what would be the shape of this array

Comment: @AkshaySehgal the final output I expect has shape `(512, 9)`. By step, individual submatrices `(250, 4)` and `(262, 4)` extracted from B are multiplied each by two different matrices `(4, 9)` extracted from A, and the results `(250, 9)` and `(262, 9)` are then stored by index into `S`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [63]: (np.ones((512,4))@np.ones((512,4,9))).shape
Out[63]: (512, 512, 9)
```

This because the first array is `broadcasted` to (1,512,4).  I think you want instead to do:

```
In [64]: (np.ones((512,1,4))@np.ones((512,4,9))).shape
Out[64]: (512, 1, 9)
```

Then remove the middle dimension to get a (512,9).

Another way:

```
In [72]: np.einsum('ij,ijk->ik', np.ones((512,4)), np.ones((512,4,9))).shape
Out[72]: (512, 9)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does the work and it is faster than the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the loop altogether, you can try this

```py
bigmask = np.arange(p)[:, np.newaxis] == categories
C = np.matmul(B, A)
res = C[np.broadcast_to(bigmask[..., np.newaxis], C.shape)].reshape(r, q)

# `res` has the same rows as the iterative `S` but in the wrong order
# so we need to reorder the rows
sort_index = np.argsort(np.broadcast_to(np.arange(r), bigmask.shape)[bigmask])
assert np.allclose(S, res[sort_index])
```

Though I'm not sure it's much faster than the iterative version.

Comment: Thanks for your input @kmkurn. Unfortunately, this is slower than the OP.

Comment: @ilibarra No worries. I had missed your snippet.